# Address Information And Customer address are not showing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5

I have upgrade m2.2.1 to m2.2.5 but address template or customer address are not working

This is not only in order view, but also everywhere that displayed the customer address by the template and calling the \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book::getAddressHtml() method.
For example, in the Customer Address Book:

a show like this template

> {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend
>   middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend
>   suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}} {{/depend}}
>   {{depend company}}{{var company}} {{/depend}} {{if street1}}{{var
>   street1}} {{/if}} {{depend street2}}{{var street2}} {{/depend}}
>   {{depend street3}}{{var street3}} {{/depend}} {{depend street4}}{{var
>   street4}} {{/depend}} {{if city}}{{var city}}, {{/if}}{{if
>   region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
>   {{var country}} {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
>   {{depend fax}} F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}} {{depend vat_id}} VAT: {{var
>   vat_id}}{{/depend}}

***Order informtion admin***
[image: Order informtion admin]

***Customer informtion admin***
[image: Customer informtion admin]

***Customer informtion frontend***
[image: Customer informtion frontend]

Comment: Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139217)

Comment: i had fix for this but it is not solution.
First i upgrade to 2.2.4 and then after 2.2.5...
i hope it helps you